# How parse DOM to get emails Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom, google-chrome-extension, html-parsing

I'am building a Chrome extension that parses the entire DOM/HTML and 
replace any found email(multiple emails) with the following div:

```
<div class="email_tmp"> found_email <span>SAVE EMAIL</span></div>
```

EXAMPLE:

```
<body>
 <div>Some Text...</div>
 <div>text a@a.com text</div>
 <div>Some Text...</div>
 <p>More Text</p>
 <div><div><span>text b@b.com text</span></div></div>
 <span>Last text</span>
</body>
```

replaced to:

```
<body>
 <div>Some Text...</div>
 <div>text <div class="email_tmp"> a@a.com <span>SAVE EMAIL</span></div> text</div>
 <div>Some Text...</div>
 <p>More Text</p>
 <div><div><span>text <div class="email_tmp"> b@b.com <span>SAVE EMAIL</span></div> text</span></div></div>
 <span>Last text</span>
</body>
```

How can I search and replace the found email by the entire div
 and the string **found_email** by the email too?
I want to replace only the found email(s) string, nothing more...
I really appreciate any help.

Comment: what would you class as a found email ?

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand you question. Thanks

Comment: Is the text on every div with class 'email_tmp' an email ?

Comment: have you try to use `xpath` with javascript to find your `div` ? @Philip Enc

Comment: I updated the question. I have to found any posible email string. If the email is wrapped by another div, that is not important. Only the string matters...

Comment: what do you want to replace it with

Comment: I want to replace any found email string by the specified div. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the total solution for what your looking for

HTML

```
<div id="main">
    sdfsdsdfsdfsdf a@a.com sdfsdfsdfsdfsdfsdf
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
var page_content = document.getElementById('main').innerHTML;
var found_email = "<div class='email_tmp'> found_email <span>SAVE EMAIL</span></div>";

//gives an array of the emails
var email = page_content.match(/([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi);

//replaces the emails to your desired content
var result = page_content.replace(email, found_email);

//replaces the changed HTML back to the 'main' div
document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = result;
```

[Here is the Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/we5jqjfy/)

Update:

If you want to replace only the text without adding any class or tags to the content of the HTML, then it gets real complicated to write a vanilla script for the same. In that case I would highly suggest you to use [this library](https://github.com/padolsey/findAndReplaceDOMText) which I found to be the perfect solution for your problem.

Its a library called `findAndReplaceDOMText` which uses inbuilt methods to solve the purpose. You just need to give the `find`(what to find) and `replace`(replacing HTML) like so,

```
findAndReplaceDOMText(document.getElementById('t'), {
  find: /([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)/gi,
  replace: '<div class='email_tmp'> found_email <span>SAVE EMAIL</span></div>'
});
```

You can obviously revert if you face any problems in implementing this library.

Also this a must read article for you - [replacing-text-in-the-dom-solved](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/replacing-text-in-the-dom-solved/)

Comment: May be this is the best answer but I cant replace the hole div(main) content with a new one because my div(main) is the body of any website like linkedin and the replace process may affect some atached event. But if I replace only the email, the probability is less to have an event atached.

Comment: @PhilipEnc - If that is the case I have updated the answer accordingly. Please check. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Slight update on @NikhilNanjappa 's original answer: my version is less efficient, but it will keep the actual email address and prepend the div and append the span and closing tags, based on the original answer.

```
var save_email_beg = "<div class='email_tmp'> ";
var save_email_end = " <span>SAVE EMAIL</span></div>";
var i = 0;
for (; i < email.length; i++) {
  var new_string = save_email_beg + email[i] + save_email_end;
  page_content = page_content.replace(email[i], new_string);
}
document.getElementById('main').innerHTML = page_content;
```

Comment: This is not the correct answer because your solution is destroying and creating again all content of the body(in my case) which brakes all current event listeners of Javascript. Try it your self!

Comment: Right, I saw your comment on @NikhilNanjappa 's first answer, so this won't work overall, but I wanted to supply the answer that included the actual email address as originally requested so that those aren't clobbered in the process.